# SQL Data truncation: Incorrect date value

Tags: sql, error-handling, oracle11g, truncation

I am getting this error.

> Data truncation: Incorrect date value: '18-JUN-13' for column
>   'dateFrom' at row 1

What could be the reason of this error?

```
INSERT INTO Booking (hotelNo, guestNo, dateFrom, dateTo, roomNo) VALUES ('01', '01', '18-JUN-13', '26-NOV-13', '01'); 
INSERT INTO Booking (hotelNo, guestNo, dateFrom, dateTo, roomNo) VALUES ('02', '01', '18-JUN-85', '26-JUN-85', '02'); 
INSERT INTO Booking (hotelNo, guestNo, dateFrom, dateTo, roomNo) VALUES ('02', '03', '18-JUN-66', '26-JUN-66', '01'); 
INSERT INTO Booking (hotelNo, guestNo, dateFrom, dateTo, roomNo) VALUES ('04', '02', '18-OCT-13', '23-OCT-13', '01'); 
INSERT INTO Booking (hotelNo, guestNo, dateFrom, dateTo, roomNo) VALUES ('02', '03', '18-JUL-87', '26-AUG-87', '01'); 
INSERT INTO Booking (hotelNo, guestNo, dateFrom, dateTo, roomNo) VALUES ('02', '03', '18-AUG-87', '26-AUG-87', '01'); 
INSERT INTO Booking (hotelNo, guestNo, dateFrom, dateTo, roomNo) VALUES ('02', '01', '18-AUG-87', '26-SEP-87', '01');
```

Comment: _incorrect date value_ seems like an obvious clue - taking a look at `to_date` might help, e.g. [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php)

Comment: Do you have a trigger on the table that is, perhaps, rejecting bookings in the past? Otherwise how are you executing these statements - there is no ORA error code shown so your client/application/etc. seems to be hiding something from you.

Comment: Hi Alex, I am new to SQL; Using SQL Fiddle for practice. I took a look at the code I had prior to this area and found nothing wrong with it. Thank you for your input!

Comment: It doesn't look like an Oracle error because it isn't one; that's a MySQL error. Did you pick the right RDBMS from the SQL Fiddle drop-down? (If you are intnding to use MySQL, please tag your question appropriately)

Comment: Hi Alex, I chose the oracle11g on the drop down box in SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't absolutely need to rely on formatted dates, [use the SQL standard `DATE` literal instead, as I've described in this blog post](http://blog.jooq.org/2015/09/15/dont-format-dates-in-sql-use-the-date-literal/), always. So, instead of:

```
INSERT INTO Booking (hotelNo, guestNo, dateFrom, dateTo, roomNo) 
VALUES ('01', '01', '18-JUN-13', '26-NOV-13', '01');
```

... write:

```
INSERT INTO Booking (hotelNo, guestNo, dateFrom, dateTo, roomNo) 
VALUES ('01', '01', DATE '2013-06-18', DATE '2013-11-26', '01');
```

If that format is a requirement (e.g. because you're loading data from some external source), use `TO_DATE()` to parse it:

```
INSERT INTO Booking (hotelNo, guestNo, dateFrom, dateTo, roomNo) 
VALUES (
  '01', 
  '01', 
  TO_DATE('18-JUN-13', 'DD-MON-YY'), 
  TO_DATE('26-NOV-13', 'DD-MON-YY'), 
  '01'
);
```